# Proof that the lower Riemann sum increases with the number of partitions

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, riemann-integration

I wish to prove:

Suppose $f:[a, b] \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ is a bounded function and $P, P^{\prime}$ are partitions of $[a, b]$ such that the list defining $P$ is a sublist of the list defining $P^{\prime}$. Then
$$
L(f, P,[a, b]) \leq L\left(f, P^{\prime},[a, b]\right) 
$$

Is the following correct?

Let $P:=\{b_1, b_2,...,b_n\}$ and $P':=\{a_1, a_2,...,a_{N}\}$. Wlog, suppose $N=n+1$ (the process outlined below may be applied $k$ times for the general $N=n+k$ case).

Let $a^*$ be the element in $P'$ that is not in $P$, and suppose $a^*\in (b_{w}, b_{w+1})$ for some $w \in \{1,....,n\}$.  So then the list of intervals corresponding to $P'$ is of the form $[b_1,b_2], [b_2,b_3],...,[b_w, a^*],[a^*, b_{w+1}],...,[b_{n-1}, b_n]$. So: $$L\left(f, P^{\prime},[a, b]\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{w-1}(b_{i}-b_{i-1})\inf_{[b_{i-1},b_i]}f +(a^*-b_{w-1})\inf_{[b_{w-1},a^*]}f + (b_{w}-a^*)\inf_{[a^*,b_{w}]}f + \sum_{w+1}^{n}(b_{i}-b_{i-1})\inf_{[b_{i}-b_{i-1}]}f \\ \geq \sum_{i=1}^{w-1}(b_{i}-b_{i-1})\inf_{[b_{i-1},b_i]}f \hspace{1mm}+(a^*-b_{w-1})\inf_{[b_{w-1},b_{w}]}f  + (b_{w}-a^*)\inf_{[b_{w-1},b_{w}]}f+\sum_{w+1}^{n}(b_{i}-b_{i-1})\inf_{[b_{i}-b_{i-1}]}f \\ =\sum_{i=1}^{w-1}(b_{i}-b_{i-1})\inf_{[b_{i-1},b_i]}f + (b_{w}-b_{w-1})\inf_{[b_{w-1},b_{w}]}f+\sum_{w+1}^{n}(b_{i}-b_{i-1})\inf_{[b_{i}-b_{i-1}]}f=L(f, P,[a, b])$$

where the inequality follows from the fact that $[b_{w-1},a^*], [a^{*}, b_{w}] \subset [b_{w-1}, b_{w}]$, and the properties of $\inf$.

Comment: That all looks good to me! Although when you said "the list of intervals corresponding to $P'$ is of the form $[b_1,b_2], [b_2,b_3],...,[b_w, a^*],[a^*, b_{w+1}],...,[a_{n-1}, a_n]$", I assume that last interval was meant to be $[b_{n-1},b_n]$? Other than that, it all seems correct!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info "This tag should be used when you have a proposed solution to a problem and you have specific concerns or doubts about the validity of that solution. A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough. "